# How to reposition a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can the button "Vote" be aligned with "View Results" as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

In this fiddle they are appearing beneath each other :

http://jsfiddle.net/5YLNT/2/

I think I need to hide the css class : '.pds-links' and then re-display it at new position somehow ?

Code behind fiddle :

```
.pds-question-top {
font-size:10pt !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-pd-link {
display:none !important;
}

.pds-box {
width:220px !important;
}

.pds-input-label {
width:85% !important;
}

.PDS_Poll {
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-answer-span {
color:#00f;
}

.pds-vote {
background-color:#424242;
}

.pds-answer-text {
color:#00f;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-answer-feedback {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-votebutton-outer {
text-align:center;
}

.pds-answer-group {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
}

.pds-input-label,.pds-answer-input {
float:left;
}

.pds-view-results,.pds-links {
color:#FFF !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-comments,.pds-return-poll {
color:#FFF !important;
}

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>

$(document).ready(function() {


});
```

Comment: .pds-links { remove display:block ... this could align the button vote

Comment: just add float:left mate .. no need to remove display:block;

Comment: You should try to use the !Important less an article about the !important tag => http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make .pds-links display inline instead of block.

http://jsfiddle.net/5YLNT/6/

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to make the votebutton float: left.

So add the following class:

```
 .pds-vote-button
 {
    float: left;
 }
```

Obviously you can tweak the margins in here as well.

This fiddle shows the new version:

http://jsfiddle.net/5YLNT/4/

Answer (score 1):

```
.pds-vote-button {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

Something like this? 
It puts the button on the left with some margin to make it more pleasant to see...